# UmbracoApiController in Plugin Area Not Found

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've created an UmbracoApiController named **FormDatasourceController** that resides in my plugin area to be used in ajax calls to get or post data.

```
[PluginController("AreaName")]
public class FormDatasourceController : UmbracoApiController
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ICountry> GetAllCountries()
    {
        return MerchelloConfiguration.Current.MerchelloCountries().Countries;
    }
}
```

and in the cshtml file I have this request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#sbmtBtn').on("click", function () {            
        $.get('~/Umbraco/AreaName/FormDatasource/GetAllCountries', null)
            .success(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                alert('failed' + e);
            });
});
});
```

However, I always get error status 404. I tried to EnableCors but with no luck.

Any advise? I'm using umbraco 7

Comment: I'm wondering if javascript is able to handle the `~` in the url since this is a C# thing (I think), either you'll have to provide the exact relative part or provide an absolute part

Comment: of course.  In fact, with an Umbraco plugin you should ignore the `~/Umbraco/` bit of the url in the $.get(..) entirely.  works for Backoffice api calls, although this will need testing (I'm being too lazy to try it out)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

For AngularJs controllers/resources in Umbraco, just do this:

change

```
$.get('~/Umbraco/AreaName/FormDatasource/GetAllCountries', null)
```

to

```
$.get('AreaName/FormDatasource/GetAllCountries', null)
```

That should get your call working.  Ignore the `~/Umbraco/` bit.

Your API call should look:

```
~/Umbraco/AreaName/FormDatasource/GetAllCountries
```

See "Plugin based controller" at https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/#plugin-based-controller.

Note, if you had inherited from 'UmbracoAuthorizedApiController' or 'UmbracoAuthorizedJsonController' your api call should be something like this:

```
~/Umbraco/backoffice/AreaName/FormDatasource/GetAllCountries
```

For more information, take a look at the bottom of this page in the documentation site under Backoffice Controllers:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/

Comment: Since the controller inherits `UmbracoApiController` and not `UmbracoAuthorizedApiController`, the backoffice part should not be necessary